# Get all table's row updated after a specific time

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-timestamp

Background:
I have an oracle table, the table doesn't have any specific column as timestamp while table creation script. This table can have millions of rows.

Example:

```
Employee {Emp_No, Name, Manager,Division, Role, Region}
```

My quest:  If any updates happened through a job on that table, can i know which all rows got updated. Does oracle have any internal timestamp for each row which i can leverage. Can i use it in query to get all records.

Reason: I need to show my team those ambiguous records weren't updated by the job we all are suspecting.

Comment: Why not add a nullable timestamp column and have the job populate it on update? That should be proof enough.

Comment: Can't add, it's a production table. Changes can not be done easily.

Comment: Does [`ora_rowscn`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953) give you the info you need, if this is a one-off task? Not clear if you need it to be more definitive than that allows... it may show the rows you're interested *weren't* updated by a recent SCN.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has `ORA_ROWSCN` Pseudocolumn. This columns returns "the conservative upper bound system change number (SCN)" of last transaction made on row or data block. This is a good estimate for when the block or row was last changed.

If your table is create with `ROWDEPENDENCIES`, `ORA_ROWSCN`  returns scn for row. `NOROWDEPENDENCIES` is the default, in which case Oracle tracks SCN at the block level.

`SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` allows you to converto scn to timestamp but for old scn it raises exception.

Answer (score 1):

Approximate update time can be retrieved with `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)`

> For each row, ORA_ROWSCN returns the conservative upper bound system
>   change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row. This
>   pseudocolumn is useful for determining approximately when a row was
>   last updated. It is not absolutely precise, because Oracle tracks SCNs
>   by transaction committed for the block in which the row resides.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm

Comment: The `scn_to_timestamp` call will fail for older rows though (i.e. probably those not updated here); possibly better to get the SCN for a time just before the update, if that is still available, and look at the `ora_rowscn` directly? I guess if you're looking at a specific row then an exception would tell you something anyway.

Comment: Excellent.  Learning something new everyday.  I didn't know either this pseudocolumn existed nor the timestamp conversion function.