# Function to query data import date when there is no "created at" column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a read-only Oracle Spatial dB. Data is imported each hour through a FME workflow. No column for the timestamp of the import has been created.

I am wondering if Oracle stores this somewhere internally anyway and whether there is some function allowing to query this data ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43003024/266304), but are you looking for recent changes, or trying to find the time for all rows (even old ones)? `ora_rowscn` can only be converted to a timestamp [for a limited period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22681705/266304). Log miner might also be an option too, again for fairly recent changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. It stores the system clock ("system change number" / SCN) of the last change in every database block (or every row if the table was created with `ROWDEPENDENCIES`).

You can use it as a *pseudocolumn*, so just add it to a query:

```
SELECT id, ora_rowscn FROM my_table;
```

For the last x days Oracle keeps a translation table that translates SCN to real time, which you can use with the function `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT id, ora_rowscn, scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn) FROM my_table;
```

Details and documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953).